# How to select alias name from a table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a language table and I want to select aliases from that table according to the specified language.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_executesql
(@parameter1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@parameter2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@code NVARCHAR(MAX),@language NVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@parameter1+' AS (SELECT @language FROM Languages WHERE code=somecolumn) '+@paramter2+' AS (SELECT @language FROM Languages WHERE code='+@code+') FROM mytable'
```

EDIT:
in Stored Procedure, I need something like that.

Thanks for answers..

Comment: Not without using dynamic Sql. Not only is it impossible, I don't see how can something like this be useful in any situation. This kind of thing needs to be done on the presentation layer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Dynamic alias without using dynamic SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072322/t-sql-dynamic-alias-without-using-dynamic-sql)

Comment: errr. for starters dont use the name `sp_executesql` - its a built-in stored procedure used for executing dynamic sql! Second point - what about my answer can you not adapt to support 2 parameters instead of 1?

Comment: @Jamiec your answer was helpful, thank you. JaydipJ's answer made my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_NameOfSP
(@parameter1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@parameter2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@code NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@language NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN 
 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SELECT TOP(1) @language=LanguageColumn FROM Languages WHERE code=somecolumn

 SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@parameter1+' AS '+@language+', '

 SELECT TOP(1) @language=LanguageColumn FROM Languages WHERE code=@code

 SET @sql=@sql+@paramter2+' AS '+@language+' FROM mytable'

 EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Replace `LanguageColumn` with proper column name from `Languages` table

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a subquery to build an alias in that way, you would need to use dynamic sql to do this.

```
DECLARE @language NVARCHAR(255)  -- or whatever type your field is
SELECT @language=language FROM Languages WHERE code=@code

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + @parameter1 + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(@language) + ' FROM MyTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

(Note the inclusion of [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) around the alias - this is a safety feature in case of your alias names having invalid characters.)

You can repeat the code above for the second parameter inside your stored procedure.

Comment: I am trying to do this in a stored procedure and I have tried to use dynamic sql, but the result has never changed.

Comment: @AlicanUzun I suggest you update your question with the stored procedure you're having problems with

Comment: Updated the answer with `QUOTENAME` since the alias name is coming from table there is a possibility to get space or special character in the alias name. So updated hope you don't mind

Comment: @Prdp I saw that, thanks for the update you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Jamiec actually I am selecting multiple columns and I need to select aliases for each. btw, column names are dynamic too.

Comment: @AlicanUzun How about you ask the *real* question you have then, instead of feeding requirements piecemeal!

Comment: @Jamiec apologies for that I am updating the question.